# Failed to install Fedora 39 on Acer Aspire 5

Tags: boot, usb, fedora, acer

I have two notebooks here at home, one of mine (Acer Aspire 5 a515-45-r8w2) and one of my girlfriend (Acer Aspire 3).

I'm trying to install Fedora Workstation 39 on the Acer Aspire 5, by booting an USB stick (SanDisk Cruzer Blade 16GB), but I'm encountering an error that I've never encountered before:

```
Warning: /dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-WS-Live-39-1-5 does not exist
Warning: /dev/root does not exist

Generating “/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt”

Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
```

When I use the `blkid` command after entering emergency mode (pressing enter), only the Windows partitions, the secondary SSD and the partitions reserved by Windows appear. The USB stick does not appear in the list.

The Acer Aspire 5 currently has Windows 11 installed, has the AMD Ryzen 7 5800U processor, and an integrated RX Vega 8 GPU.

The Acer Aspire 3 is also running Windows 11, and has the Intel Celeron processor, with an integrated GPU.

On the Acer Aspire 3, with the same USB stick, no problems occur, the boot occurs normally...

What I've already tried:

- I mounted the USB stick with Rufus, using both the MBR and GPT file systems;
- I mounted the USB stick with Rufus, using both ISO and DD modes;
- I mounted the USB stick with Etcher;
- I mounted the USB stick with Fedora Media Writer;
- I downloaded the ISO again and checked the checksum;
- Leave Fast Boot in the BIOS as Enabled and Disabled;
- Leave Secure Boot in the BIOS as Enabled and Disabled;
- I tried using the USB stick on both the USB 2.0 and USB 3.2 ports;
- I also tried adding the “`ro`” parameter to the boot command line (I saw it in an old video on YouTube);
- I tried to start the media using the three options that appear at Fedora boot: Start; Check (or Verify, now I don't remember how it's written) and Start; and through the option in Troubleshoot…

Everything I tried returned the same error...

Has anyone come across this? Do you know what's happening and how I can fix it?

I've already searched the internet for how to fix this, and I'm out of alternatives...

In emergency mode, I typed the commands `cd /dev/disk/by-label` and `ls -l`. Only the symlinks for the Main SSD (Acer, ESP and Recovery) and the Secondary SSD were displayed, the boot media (USB stick) was not displayed.

So, I decided to take a look at `journalctl`, and I noticed that before the `fedora dracut-initqueue` warnings started, there is the following log:

> fedora kernel: usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd

Apparently, due to this reset the process does not continue (I could be wrong)…

[image: Print of this excerpt]